# Colormap in mplot3d not corresponding to Z values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, 3d, mplot3d

I'm trying to create a 3D plot of a spectrogram and it may just be a misunderstanding on my part about how plot_surface works, but I expect the colours on the plot to correspond to the Z-value, or the height of the plot. Instead, I get this

[image]

Smaller spikes have colours corresponding to higher values and vice versa.

I notice that the axes have different values but I can't quite understand the documentation for this function; what exactly is being plotted by the colour map and if it isn't the Z values, how do I make it so?

```
x, y = np.meshgrid(t[t_start:t_end]-tprior, freqs[f_start:f_end])
z = abs(X_3d)
norm=None
vmin=None
vmax=None
cmap='jet'
aspect=50

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1,1))
ax = mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D(fig,rect=(0,0,20,5),azim=-90,elev=10)
plot = ax.plot_surface(x,y,z,norm=norm,vmin=vmin,vmax=vmax,cmap=cmap)

fig.colorbar(plot, anchor=(-1,0))
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is colored are the faces of the grid. But each face has 4 corner points. So if the values of those corners are substantially different, e.g. 3 points are 0, one is 3000, the peak that is 3000 units high, might still be colored in blue, due to the other 3 points being really small. The only way to circumvent this is to either densify the grid, or to assign custom colors according to a different metric.

Comment: I see. Thank you!